# New table with all columns as differences between two base tables columns

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, dynamic-sql, outer-join, create-table

I am using Postgres 9.1 and have two tables (`tab1` and `tab2`). I wish to create a third table (`tab3`) where each column is the difference between respective columns in these tables, i.e. `tab3.col1 = (tab1.col1 - tab2.col1)`. However my tables `tab1` and `tab2` have a large number columns. Is there an efficient way to create table `tab3`?

If I were to hard code my desired output I would plan to use the code below. However I wish to avoid this as I have over 60 columns to create and want to avoid any hard-coding errors. The columns may not be in the same order across the two tables, however the naming is consistent across tables.

```
CREATE TABLE tab3 AS
  SELECT a.col1_01 - b.col2_01 AS col3_01,
         a.col1_02 - b.col2_02 AS col3_02,
         ...
         ...
   FROM tab1 a FULL JOIN tab2 b USING (permno, datadate);
```

Comment: No, there's no convenient shorthand for this.

Comment: Not to worry. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the whole statement from information in the system catalog (or information schema) and execute it dynamically with a [**`DO`** command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html). That's what I would do.

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN

EXECUTE (
SELECT 'CREATE TABLE tab3 AS
SELECT '
|| string_agg(format('a.%1$I - b.%1$I AS %1$I', attname)
            , E'\n     , ' ORDER BY attnum)
|| '
FROM   tab1      a
FULL   JOIN tab2 b USING (permno, datadate)'
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'tab1'::regclass
AND    attnum > 0        -- exclude system columns (neg. attnum)
AND    NOT attisdropped  -- no dropped (dead) columns
);

END
$do$;
```

Assuming that `tab1` and `tab2` are visible in your [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777).

Produces and executes what you requested *exactly*. Just replace dummy table and column names with your real names.

Read about [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) and [`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) in the manual.

More information in these related answers:
[Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
[Prepend table name to each column in a result set in SQL? (Postgres specifically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179648/prepend-table-name-to-each-column-in-a-result-set-in-sql-postgres-specifically/21005694#21005694)