# POSTGRES SELECT AS

Tags: postgresql, alias

I am joining two tables house and tower, both have some of the same column names such as id, created_at, deleted, address etc. I wonder if it is possible to return the columns in the following fashion: house.created_at, house.id, tower.created_at, tower.id etc. I know I can query with AS, I was wondering if it is possible to query something like this: `SELECT house.* AS house, tower.* AS tower`. I tried it like this, but it was not valid SQL. Any idea how I can chase the column names prefix easily ?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You have to write the alias for each column individually

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5179648/330315

Comment: Why isn't using the table alias in the select list sufficient?