# How to give alias for columns with same name after joining two tables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, column-alias

Hi Guys I'm doing inner join for two tables and selecting all the columns from both tables. But I'm getting three cols with same name like id, created_at and updated_at.

Query:

```
SELECT addresses.* , facilities.* FROM facilities
      INNER JOIN addresses
      ON facilities.main_address_id = addresses.id
```

Is there any possible way that I can mention alias for above cols having same name while selecting all cols with * ?

Help of any kind would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: No, there is no automatic way to rename columns. Related (if not duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179648

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do this other than aliasing each column separately.

But if your query will be repetitive you could create VIEW:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW facilities_addresses AS
SELECT 
    addresses.column AS "addresses_column", 
    facilities.column AS "facilities_column"
FROM facilities
    INNER JOIN addresses ON (facilities.main_address_id = addresses.id)
```

and then you can query:

```
SELECT * FROM facilities_addresses
```

Answer (score -1):

yes you can

```
SELECT 
   addr.id as addressesId ,
   addr.created_at as addresses_created_at,
   addr.updated_at as addresses_update_at,
   fac.id as facilitiesId,
   fac.created_at as facilities_created_at,
   fac.updated_at as facilities_updated_at FROM facilities as fac
      INNER JOIN addresses as addr
      ON facilities.main_address_id = addresses.id
```

Comment: yep have to mention all the column name in the query